# How can I edit a live webpage without causing chaos for the page's visitors during my editing session?

Tags: php, html

Pardon me if these very basic questions have been asked and answered many times, but several hours of searching turned up nothing pertinent.

(1) After "going live" with a webpage, a Stackoverflow developer wants to make some changes to a page, but does not want those changes to "go live" until he has completed a cycle of PROTOTYPING and TESTING the changes (you know, basic SDLC). How does he do this in the website was live?

(2) An even more basic rephrasing of the question: While I am spending, say, 30 minutes making updates to an existing, live webpage, it appears that any visitor to that webpage during that time will observe every incremental change (including inadvertent blunders, typos, etc.) that I am making IN REAL TIME. I must be missing something really obvious here, so forgive me! How do I make changes to a currently-live webpage without causing such chaos during my edit sessions?

Comment: Have a testing and live version of your site. Have almost all settings the same (display errors on testing, not on live).

Comment: Maybe a maintenance mode can be help, You know ; only developer can see the pages in the maintenance mode.

Comment: @chris85 I think that will be harder and confusing, two copies of all pages.

Comment: @EmreY Sure! u right, but we want do that changes without Maintenance. Im only looking for  professionals opinions, like yours :)

Comment: In the section you are working on use an if condition where what you are working on only displays when your user is logged in. This will only prevent people from seeing what you are doing but the page will suffer errors if you have any syntax errors.

Comment: I don't think you're going to like any of the ways i'd suggest because they all involve more tools and/or files. Nothing should be tested/worked on on live.

Comment: Also, if you are not interested in a preview and live version of your site, you can also try writing a simple cache script that will cache your page and load from it while you are working on it. When complete, just disable the caching and it will start loading the dynamic page again.

Comment: @Rasclatt Sounds like good, cache system would be usefull.  chris85 im not here to dislike your valuable insights. Im just looking for insights from other developers on the world. :)

Comment: I don not understand what _going live_ has to do with having a _development server_? I know your question is specifically about changing the code of a page on a live website without causing problems with visitors, but I do not understand why is it difficult for you to make those changes on your development(local) severs, check them, debug them and finally upload the final version on the live server in just a blink of an eye?

Comment: Anyways, if you are talking about only one page, you can make a copy of that exact page on the live server, make changes in it and after everything was in order, replace it with the original one. in this case only you have access to that new page and visitors are not even aware of it.

Comment: I work on a real site and we have live, dev and test sites with almost all the same code. Dev is where we make changes (after we develop on local project)changes. Then we move to test which is almost exactly like live, then if all is good we move to live. Don't try to cheat, do it like the pros.

Comment: Cool. Make sure to setup different databases for each test, dev and live. Just take the live database and use it for test and dev. Then every few weeks you can copy from live to dev and test again.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing so many bad comments and one bad answer. You never work on the live pages. What if you break it? The fact that you are asking this question tells me that you are not good enough not to make a mistake.

There is really only one good way to do this in my opinion.

Create a sub domain dev.whatever.com and put your current live site there. Work on your local project to start, when you are happy with that result, then move it to your dev site to make sure there are no issues, do it all there first, then when you are happy, you move to live.

Comment: For good or ill, the OP said they were not interested in duplicating their site. Obviously a preview/live site scenario is the way to go, my *"bad answer"* is the closest scenario I can think of that does not include preview/live versions.

Comment: Further, there are a variety of web applications that use a system whereby you don't need a development server/subdomain to make simple typo changes or layout changes. As mentioned by other posters, a maintenance mode, found in web apps like Wordpress, Magento, etc or what-have use caches and databases to keep pages in a static state until a cache is flushed or page is moved to live mode. Updating/creating code in a live environment, sure, not the greatest plan, but page layouts and text changes hardly need a dev environment to be successful editing environments.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save a copy of the page with a different file name. Upload it and work off that until it works how you want. No one will know the page exists except you so no one will see any issues. Once you are happy with it just use that pages code.

Comment: We have many visitors, when we upload new file and on the same time someone will try to load the page than bamm it will crash :) We dont want live a problem like that.

Comment: I don't think you understand what im saying. No one will be loading the page because its not linked to from your site, so no one knows its there but you.

Answer (score 0):

I think working on a local repository and learning version control would be best. This way, incase you do happen to completely break your code, you can revert to a previous working version without any worries. You can also use a local server this way only you can see the current updates going on with your code. Once you are happy with everything and all code works, you can then push the changes onto your remote server.

version control: https://git-scm.com/

Answer (score -1):

Further to my comment, here is a simple caching page script that uses a define for allowing the page to run in cache mode or dynamic mode. Toggle `CACHESITE` to false to return it to live rendering of the page. This would need to be expanded out to bypass the cache if you are an admin (or some other trigger that you decide), so you can see the changes being made but the user sees the cached page:

```
<?php
    // If true, cache this page
    define("CACHESITE",true);

    function CachePage($content = '',$saveto = 'index.php')
        {
            ob_start();
            echo $content;
            $data   =   ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            if(CACHESITE) {
                    // If you have a define for site root, use instead
                    $dir    =   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/temp/';
                    if(is_file($cached = $dir.$saveto)) {
                            include($cached);
                            return;
                        }

                    if(!is_dir($dir))
                        mkdir($dir,0755,true);

                    $cfile  =   fopen($cached,'a');
                    fwrite($cfile,$data);
                    fclose($cfile);
                }

            return $data;
        }

    // Whatever your content is, it needs to be in a string
    // Use output buffering if you have include pages
    $test   =   'test is the best'.rand();
    echo CachePage($test,'thispage.php');
?>
```

At any rate, there are lots of ways to do this sort of thing, but caching works relatively well.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, But i didnt request a code :) Just ideas enough :)

Comment: No problem, I just supplied an example of what I mean regarding caching your page. It may or may not work for what you are trying to do, but I personally use caching to do html revisions and such all the time using this method.